# how to join two table by time

Tags: sql, pandas, database, join, mariadb

A:

| CODE | TIMESTAMP | MODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-09-01 23:12:43 | Sleep |
| B | 2020-09-02 22:09:12 | Weak |

B:

| CODE | TIMESTAMP | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-08-01 11:12:43 | Go |
| A | 2020-09-01 22:09:12 | Stop |
| A | 2020-09-02 06:12:43 | Stop |
| A | 2020-09-03 11:07:43 | Stop |
| B | 2020-09-03 22:09:12 | Go |

final table:

| CODE | A_TIMESTAMP | MODE | Action | B_TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-09-01 23:12:43 | Sleep | Stop | 2020-09-02 06:12:43 |
| B | 2020-09-02 22:09:12 | Weak | Go | 2020-09-03 22:09:12 |

What I want is to join table A and table B (key=Code), but if the timestamp of table B is greater than the value of table A, this is the method to join only the first one.

A table has more than 10 million rows

The number of rows in table B is also 1 million.

I can use dask, pyspark, pandas, sql all. How can I get it efficiently?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in 90 percent of scenarios getting the data the way you want from database engine is the fastest and most efficient way.

If you always have one record in table B with timestamp greater than in Table A then  a simple join is the answer :

```
select * from A
join B 
on A.Code = B.Code
and A.TimeStamp < B.TimeStamp
```

If not :

```
select
    *
from
    A
cross apply (
    select TOP 1 *
    from B 
    where A.Code = B.Code
      and A.TimeStamp < B.TimeStamp
    order by B.TimeStamp
)
```

Comment: There is not always one.
So, can I use cross apply?

Comment: Then yes , the second query is your answer

Comment: @kang as you see your question has been closed, please edit your question to improve it and add proper sql engine you are using , ( by the way my query is written in sql server format ) , also please accpet/upvote the answer if it helped , thank you